# C# checking if object is null - weird result

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

The following piece of sharepoint code is attempting to list all the user profile properties as well as their values

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(args[0], SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
        {

            var profileManager = new UserProfileManager(SPServiceContext.GetContext(site));
            UserProfile userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(args[1]);

            foreach (var Property in userProfile.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Property DisplayName = " + Property.DisplayName + "; " + "Property Name = " + Property.Name);
                if (userProfile[Property.Name] != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("user profile property value " + Property.Name + " is not null");
                    Console.WriteLine("property Value = " + userProfile[Property.Name].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("property Value = null");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this produces the following output :

[image: output]

This shows the exception is coming on the line where it is trying to check if the user profile property value is null

```
if (userProfile[Property.Name] != null)
```

But i am already comparing it to null. So why should it give the error that the object is null?

Can someone please give some clarification?

the userProfile is not null , the Property.Name is also not null and i am checking if the userProfile[Property.Name] != null. But it blows up with the error. 
What on earth is going on?

Comment: I don't have the sharepoint references loaded, but it would see that the indexer function on userProfile is internally throwing a null exception before the comparison to the result of the function is made to null in your if statement.

Comment: Are you sure that your PDB files are being rebuilt and that the stack trace is up-to-date?

Comment: alternative, try to put in `watch` window this element: `userProfile["ADGuid"]`

Comment: @Ian You can tell that it's not null from the output printed before it throws.

Comment: I agree with @GrantWinney, It is most likely that the Property.Name is null;

Comment: @GrantWinney We know it's not, because it's printed out as "ADGuid" on the line above.

Comment: @hivie7510 but `Property.Name` can be printed out...

Comment: I didn't see the scroll.  Definitely a weird problem.

Comment: Maybe you're enumerating on the wrong object? According to [UserProfile docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.aspx), it has an enumerator on it's own - maybe try `foreach (var Property in userProfile)`?

Comment: @qbik will try but i am wondering - if you are correct then why is it working for the first 2 properties.. it did print the values for the UserProfile_GUID and the SID

Comment: @GrantWinney You don't need to do that.  Either the stack trace of the error is the line the OP actually said, or the *actual* stack trace indicates that the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @GrantWinney i posted the exact output from the program

Comment: Are you certain the userProfile[Property.Name].Value is not null?

Comment: @RamlinRose i think you are right. I updated the code and output in my question. You can see that the error does not occur when it checks for null but it occurs when it tries to print the string output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming userProfile[Property.Name].Value is not null. Try this

```
if (userProfile[Property.Name] != null 
        && userProfile[Property.Name].Value != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("property Value = " + userProfile[Property.Name].Value.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: from the updated code and output , it is clear that error occurs in this line Console.WriteLine("property Value = " + userProfile[Property.Name].ToString());  Seems like the ToString() implementation displays the Value object like you are saying

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
if (userProfile[Property.Name] != null)
```

When `Property` is null, attempting to get `.Name` from a null value will throw the `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Thang Coder, if the look at the line just above where the error occurs the Property.Name is being printed

Comment: Can you please update your question to show the entire stack trace? Thanks